# Angular no puede acceder a una propiedad

Tags: nodejs, angular, typescript, mongoose

estoy tratando de replicar un ejercicio de un carrito de compras, para ver si puedo implementarlo más adelante, pero tengo un pequeño problema, cuando quiero cargar los elementos que se han guardado en una tabla de carrito, angular me dice que no pudo acceder a la propiedad _id porque esta indefinida, tengo un servicio que hace este proceso y me carga los datos en un componente pero igualmente, aunque los datos guarden correctamente, estos luego no pueden ser renderizados por el error.

```
getCartItems(): Observable<CartItem[]> {
    return this.http.get<CartItem[]>(this.URL + '/cart').pipe(
      map((result: any[]) => {
        let cartItems: CartItem[] = [];

        for (let item of result) {
          let productExits = false;

          for (let i in cartItems) {
            if (cartItems[i].productId === item.product._id) {
              Swal.fire({
                title: 'Ya tienes este producto en tu carrito',
                showClass: {
                  popup: 'animate__headShake',
                },
                hideClass: {
                  popup: 'animate__backOutUp',
                },
              });
              productExits = true;
              break;
            }
          }

          if (!productExits) {
            cartItems.push(new CartItem(item._id, item.produtc));
          }
        }
        return cartItems;
      })
    );
  }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el modelo,

```
import { Product } from './products';

export class CartItem {
  _id: string;
  productId: string;
  name: string;
  price: number;
  constructor(_id: '', product: Product) {
    this._id = _id;
    this.productId = product._id;
    this.name = product.name;
    this.price = product.price;
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Respecto a los comentarios, sobre mi API, solo hago una consulta a los carritos de compra que se almacenan y este es el codigo:

```
cartController.getAllCarts = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const carts = await model_cart.find();
    return res.json(carts);
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
};
```

Me imagino que en esta consulta debo enviar tambien los datos del producto.

Comment: Hola, lo que esta `undefined` no es el `_id`, si no todo el objeto que deberia contenerlo. Cual es la linea `shopcart.service.ts:40` ? Ahi esta el inicio de la solucion.

Comment: Me imagino que el problema viene de `item.product._id`. Haz un `console.log` de `item` para ver por si la sintaxis que estas usando es correcta.

Comment: Hola, la linea 40 de `shopcart.service` es `cartItems.push(new CartItem(item._id, item.product));` . Respecto al `console.log`, me trae el objeto item, que seria el producto

Comment: El `console.log` lo puse antes de entrar al condicional de `!productExits` Y me muestra esto, https://prnt.sc/swrp3l

Comment: `item` no tiene la propiedad `product`. Ese es el problema. Puedes comprobarlo por favor con `console.log('item.product')` para corroborar que verdaderamente esta nulo?

Comment: `item.product` Llega como undefined.

Comment: Si, ese es el problema y se nota cuando en el constructor de tu model haces `this.productId = product._id;`. Hasta ese momento te arroja el error. Tienes que revisar tu api

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109125/discussion-between-daniel-morales-and-legna).

Answer (score 1):

Debes corregir la siguiente linea para que te funcione:

```
 if (!productExits) {                             //Aqui
            cartItems.push(new CartItem(item._id, item));
          }
```

Y esta otra linea en tu model:

```
this.productId = product.productId;
```

Lo que estas recibiendo en `result: any []` es en realidad una lista de productos. `item.product` no existe. Asumiendo que item es el `product` esto resolvera el problema.

Comment: La primera linea donde hice el cambio, digamos que solo me funciono para cuando el carrito esta completamente vacío en mongo, al hacer el primer save, me guarda bien, pero si quiero añadir otro producto, vuelve y marca error y si refresco la página, el producto que se había añadido, ya no se renderiza en mi componente y sigue saliendo el mismo error de `_id undefined`, la linea que me dices que agregue al model, no vendría siendo lo mismo si lo dejo igual?, porque en el model de products, ese campo si se llama _id

Answer (score 1):

al final logré dar con la solución, gracias a la respuesta anterior, cambie la linea

```
if (!productExits) {
            cartItems.push(new CartItem(item._id, item)); //Aqui
          }
```

Y este if, `if (cartItems[i]._id === item.productId)`, lo tenía como item.product._id, al hacer este cambio, ya quedo funcionando como queria el componente.

Comment: Excelente. Que bueno que encontraste el problema.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda.